# list element 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, string, list, dataframe

```py
jlink1=[]
import time
#for url in l2:
jdata=len(l2)
for i in range(jdata):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    url =l2[i] 
    page = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')     
    for tr in soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class':'fsdfsdfsdfsdfi'}):
        sikko1 =[ x.get("href") for x in tr.find_all('a',)]  
        jlink1.append(sikko1)    
        print(sikko1)
```

```
['../Page/../sdfsdfsdfsdf']
['../Page/../sdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdf']
['../Page/../sdfsfsdfsdfsdfsfsfd']
['../Page/../sdfsfsdfsfsdfsdfsdf']
```

İ have just like this list and can't convert string for use this code

```
jlink1.replace('../..','https://www.blablfsddfda.com')
```

Help please

Comment: please share your full code.

Comment: Please add more details related to what you are trying to achieve. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace the following piece of code:

```py
sikko1 =[ x.get("href") for x in tr.find_all('a',)]
```

to the following:

```py
sikko1 =[ x.get("href").replace('../','https://www.blablfsddfda.com') for x in tr.find_all('a',)]
```